# What's the mixture of carbon and haemoglobin called

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I know of oxyhaemogloblin , the mixture of oxygen and haemoglobin  , but carbon and haemoglobin combination is what's confusing

Comment: Carbon and hemoglobin??? Hemoglobin is made of carbon and other elements; it doesn't transport it. [Do you mean CO or CO2 perhaps?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin)

Comment: Is there a name for it other than Deoxyhemoglobine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to agree with the comment left by @anongoodnurse and assume you are looking for the terms that define CO2 + hemoglobin and CO + hemoglobin.

CO2 + hemoglobin = [Carbaminohemoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbaminohemoglobin)

CO + hemoglobin = [Carboxyhemoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboxyhemoglobin)